# Keeping footer down at the bottom with Material-UI Expansion Drawers

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI@next for my React app. In one particular component, I am displaying a list of items using [Expansion Panels](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/expansion-panels/). I also have a simple `<Footer />` component that looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import styled from "styled-components";
import Typography from "material-ui/Typography";

const FooterContainer = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100px !important ;
  background: #6cf;
`;

class Footer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FooterContainer>
        <Typography variant="title">Footer Text</Typography>
      </FooterContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default Footer;
```

This is the code snippet where I am using `<Footer />` under the list of items:

```
  render() {
    return this.props.isFetching ? (
      <Typography>Loading...</Typography>
    ) : (
      <Container>
        <StyledTitle variant="display1" gutterBottom color="secondary">
          Listings
        </StyledTitle>
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
          {this.renderListings()}
        </Grid>
        <Footer />
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

,where `renderListings()` is just doing an iteration over an array and displaying the results in an Expansion Panel:

```
...
      <Grid key={listing._id} item xs={12} sm={12} lg={12}>
        <StyledExpansionPanel>
          <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
            <ExpansionPanelColumn>
              <Typography>{listing.name}</Typography>
            </ExpansionPanelColumn>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <Divider />
          <ExpansionPanelDetails>
            <Typography>Notes: {listing.notes}</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Divider />
        </StyledExpansionPanel>
      </Grid>
...
```

The problem is that when the Expansion Panels are closed, the footer displays fine, however when the expansion panels are open, they get under the footer and the footer is no longer at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, can you add a `CodeSandbox`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved this by using `flex`. In a nutshell, all I needed to do is change the `<Container />` component style as follows:

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
```

When I wrap the vertical sections in a flex container and choose which ones you want to expand, they’ll automatically take up all the available space in their container.

Answer (score 16):

```
footer {
  margin-top:calc(5% + 60px);
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This works fine for me

Comment: I preferred this over the accepted answer. the min-height 100vh gave my page some issues. Especially because the content is never the same on any page for me

Comment: Worked for me after I added `position: 'sticky'`

Comment: Yes but it will stay on the bottom of the screen and always shown regardless of the size of the page. Sometimes it confuses the user

Comment: Agree with @karthikaeyan . I think a footer should be shown only after one scrolled to the bottom of the page

Comment: Why `5%+60px`? I think it should be 100%-60px. It's not working for me.

Comment: How to apply calc when you use sx={{}} ?

Comment: @ReactPotato sx={{ marginTop: "calc(2% + 10px)"}}>